# how to use while() with json?

Tags: php

i have a ajax that needs to return some values, but if i use a **`while()`** to get all the result from my db, the return is "nothing".

**js:**

```
$.post("ajax/file.ajax.php", 
  { 
    cache: false
  }, 
  function(data){ 
    alert(data.region);
  },'json'
);
```

**php:**

```
while(!$res->EOF)
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $return_data = array('value'=>''.$res->fields['VALUE'].'','region'=>''.$res->fields['REGION'].'');
        echo json_encode($return_data);

        $res->MoveNext();
    }
```

so, how can i use the while with json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create an array and then `array.push` the row you are generating onto the end of it.

For example:

**PHP**

```
$array = array();

while(!$res->EOF) {
    $dataFromDB = array('value'=>''.$res->fields['VALUE'].'','region'=>''.$res->fields['REGION'].'');
    $array[] = $dataFromDB; //or array_push($array, $dataFromDB); 

    $res->MoveNext();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

**JS:**

```
$.post("ajax/file.ajax.php", 
  { 
    cache: false
  }, 
  function(data){ 
    for(n in data) {
        alert(data[n].region);
    }
  },'json'
);
```

Then output the json encoded array to finish.

You should also move your header out of the while loop and put it just before you echo the new array.

Comment: dont know why, but the its returning "undifined".

Comment: Use the JS I just added above

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

PHP:

```
$return_data = array();
while(!$res->EOF){
    $return_data[] = array(
        'value' => $res->fields['VALUE'],
        'region' => $res->fields['REGION']
    );
    $res->MoveNext();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
```

jQuery:

```
$.post("ajax/file.ajax.php", {cache: false}, function(data){ 
    for(var i in data){
        alert(data[i].region);
    }
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("ajax/file.ajax.php", 
  { 
    cache: false
  }, 
  function(data){ 
    //alert(data.region);
    if(data.region.length>0){
       for(var i=0;i<data.region.length;i++) {
            alert(data.region[i]);
       }
    }
  },'json'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$return_data = array();

while(!$res->EOF)
{
    $return_data[] = array('value'=>''.$res->fields['VALUE'].'','region'=>''.$res->fields['REGION'].'');

    $res->MoveNext();
}

echo json_encode($return_data);
```

So you only echo the data once, and it's an array with all of the data. In the JS you'll just have to loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

Try building up the array and then do a single json_encode of the contents. The PHP code you listed is sending sequential fragments of json that are not valid as a whole.

```
$data = array();
while(!$res->EOF)
{           
    $data[] = array('value'=>''.$res->fields['VALUE'].'','region'=>''.$res->fields['REGION'].'');
    $res->MoveNext();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to look at:

1. Don't use `header()` in a loop. Headers can't be sent after sending content, which you do with the `echo`. Send it once before sending any content (json).
2. You aren't sending valid JSON. Since you echo each result, your output looks like this:

   ```
   {"value":"foo1", "region":"bar1"}
   {"value":"foo2", "region":"bar2"}
   ```

   JSON arrays need to be within brackets (http://www.json.org/).

   ```
   [
       {"value":"foo1", "region":"bar1"},
       {"value":"foo2", "region":"bar2"}
   ]
   ```

So, form your query results array, then send encoded content:

```
<?php

$return_data = array();
while (!$res->EOF) {
    $return_data[] = array(
        'value' => '' . $res->fields['VALUE'] . '',
        'region' => '' . $res->fields['REGION'] . ''
    );

    $res->MoveNext();
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);

?>
```